# Android studio build failed on Dolphin version

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have downloaded and started use of Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1

below are the configurations :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio2\jre
```

while build the application get the error as :

```
The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your project uses Java 8 or Java 11? If you are using Java 8. Kindly migrate to Java 11